# QQmlListProperty<T> : Why does the following getter function work?

Tags: c++, qml, qqmllistproperty

i am a newbie in qml and have difficulties to understand example code for the use of QQmlListProperty:

I do not understand this getter function in the chartitem.cpp file (without any reference to the private m_bars in the chartitem.h file) :

```
QQmlListProperty<BarItem> ChartItem::bars()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<BarItem>(this, 0,
                &ChartItem::append_bar,0, 0, 0);
    // where is the reference to m_bars ?
}
```

Which data will be returned ? There is no reference to the `private Qlist<BarItem*> m_bars` which should contain the returned data.

Here are the important code snippets of the header and implementation files ...

```
/*---------- chartitem.h file : -----------*/
    class ChartItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<BarItem> bars READ bars NOTIFY barsChanged)
    public:
        ChartItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
        void paint(QPainter *painter);
        QQmlListProperty<BarItem> bars();
        ...

        Q_SIGNALS:
        void barsChanged();
    private:
        static void append_bar(QQmlListProperty<BarItem> *list, BarItem *bar);
        QList<BarItem*> m_bars;
        ...
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------*/


/*------------- chartitem.cpp file --------*/
...
QQmlListProperty<BarItem> ChartItem::bars()
{
    return QQmlListProperty<BarItem>(this, 0,
                &ChartItem::append_bar,0, 0, 0);
    // where is the reference to m_bars ?
}

void ChartItem::append_bar(QQmlListProperty<BarItem> *list, BarItem *bar)
{
ChartItem *chart = qobject_cast<ChartItem *>(list->object);
if (chart) {
    bar->setParent(chart);
    chart->m_bars.append(bar);
    chart->barsChanged();
}
...
/*-----------------------------------------*/
```

Can someone explain my error in reasoning ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [public members](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) of `QQmlListProperty`. The only thing that would allow you to observe the data is `operator==`. So it doesn't matter that the data isn't present, because no-one can observe it's absence.

Presumably the only thing you can do with `bars` is add elements to the underlying `ChartItem` (by some QML magic), because that is the only operation provided. In some sense it is thus a **write-only** property